# WebIX Loading Icon Spin until method is completed

Tags: javascript, node.js, load, webix

In Webix I have a method like this

```
function show_progress_icon(delay) {
  $$("topView").disable();
  $$("topView").showProgress({
    type: "icon",
    delay: delay,
    hide: true
  });
  setTimeout(function () {
    $$("topView").enable();
  }, delay);
}
```

This is based on a delay given as input.

Instead, how do I perform showProgress in starting of some code and hide at the end of the code?

Example, I want this

```
function A() {
//showProgress Icon
//Do Some Tasks
//hideProgress Icon
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$$("topView").hideProgress()`. Remove `delay` and `hide` from `showProgress`.